# Locking Graphic Elements in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, layouts

I am using ArcMap 10.5.

I'm trying to lock graphic elements (rectangle in my case) to prevent it from being selected and moved when I'm working in layout mode.

I looked up ESRI help and got this explanation bellow (Image 1), but when I right-click my graphic element in Layout mode I do not see any Lock Mode option (Image 2).

What am I doing wrong?

Image 1
[image]
Image 2

[image]

Comment: Do you have a Production Mapping license? This sounds like you need one.

Comment: @danak I have 3D Analyst license. Not sure what is Production Mapping license and how to obtain it.

Comment: It is expensive, and is used for processing of lots of maps and data to various standards. So, not worth it for what you want to do.

Comment: @danak but what I don't understand is why the ESRI help show the step-by-step how to lock graphic elements but would not mention "Production Mapping" license?

Comment: It is two lines under the title in your graphic with the warning triangle "Available with Production Mapping."

Comment: @danak yeah, I don't have that production mapping license. But I find it hard to believe having this license is the only way you can lock graphic elements in layout view, it's such a basic map operation. Do you know of any work-arounds?